# Drag and Drop icons from Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am stuck up with a problem and that is annoying me. I hope someone can help me on this.

Please imagine I have a **Icon** called **Communication**. On click of that Icon, I should get a tooltip (should kept open until I click outside or on the same **Communication** Icon)

So the tooltip should contain few other icons like **Phone**, **Email**, **In Person** Icons and I should be able to drag and drop them in another div element.

Note that the Icons from the **Communication**'s Tooltip should not be deleted.

Below is the sample, that I have found and modified a bit.

```
    $(function() {
        $( document ).tooltip({
            items: "input",
            content: function() {
                return $('.myPopover').html();
            },
            position: {
                my: "center bottom-20",
                at: "center top",
                using: function( position, feedback ) {
                    $( this ).css( position );
                    $( "<div>" )
                            .addClass( "arrow" )
                            .addClass( feedback.vertical )
                            .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
                            .appendTo( this );
                }
            }
        });

        $('.fireTip').click(function () {
            if(!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
                $('#age').trigger('mouseover');
                $(this).addClass('open');
            } else {
                $('#age').trigger('mouseout');
                $(this).removeClass('open');
            }

        })

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AK7pv/961/

I am actually expecting similar to this example, but instead of the list tags, I want the Icons to be arranged in series and it should be drag-gable to other div elements.

Please assist me, whether this is possible or not. We can use **Jquery, Javascript, Kendo UI** to do this.

Comment: from  "arrange in series" you mean "inline": icon1, icon2, icon3? like this?

Comment: @abdullahDanyal: Yes, what i wanted to convey is, the Icons should be placed one after the other and It can be dragged and dropped to another div, but the Icons from the Source (Tool tip popup, shouldn't be removed at any cause) remains there always.